# Accept rate on profile?

Tags: support, profile-page, accept-rate

How do you see your accept rate without going to a question that you asked?

Comment: Simple, you don't. ;)

Comment: @chrisaycock no, actually it's not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nope, they haven't put that functionality in yet, you have to go look at a question.  I'm sure it'll be in your profile in [6-8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19478/13295).

Comment: +1 for the mention of the eternal "6-8 weeks".

Answer (score 7):

As a start, can I suggest that the `xx% accept rate` label should, for the user concerned, **link to the questions that need an answer to be chosen as accepted**. This page could be done as a filter after [votes] [newest] [views] [recent] on the user profile page.

Answer (score 2):

The question I'd have is why you would need to see your own acceptance rate? All the information is there in the list of questions you've asked.

I suppose a feature that allowed you to sort/filter the questions by accepted/unaccepted would be possibly useful if you haven't been reading your inbox and paying attention to updates on questions you asked.

Comment: For new users perhaps? Also if you forgot to accept one, and the list isn't filtered to show you which one you forgot to accept?

Comment: I would need/want to see my own accept rate if it is lacking. Knowing that the rating exists would give me cause to improve it... and that's the point of having it in the first place.

Comment: @Robert Cartaino - for your 1 question on SO? :) Seriously though, most people would be able to glance through even a dozen pages of questions pretty quickly and infer a rough estimate from it.

Comment: At that point, I would just rather look at one of my questions.