# Handling questions asking for data, statistics or marketing share?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

I often see questions asking for data, statistics or marketing share (that are *not* about SE) and I'm finding it hard to tell that they are OT. But as far as I can tell, those answers are likely to be rarely updated with up-to-date data, so they might not be good for SE. [Example from Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/4448/205764)

I'm wondering if there's a guideline about this situation.

Answer (score 2):

The example you give, while not a 'traditional' Stack Exchange Q&A, is a *good* question/answer, for the following reasons:

- it's a relevant topic (reflected by the number of upvotes)
- it contains an official link from Google itself, which should always be up to date
- it's maintained well [by the community](https://android.stackexchange.com/posts/4448/revisions); in the past, such answer would've automatically be converted to a Community Wiki.

In fact, the last bullet is probably the only thing I'd change to that Q&A: make it a Community Wiki so that it's easier to keep it up to date.

---

> those answers are likely to be rarely updated with up-to-date data

While that is a valid concern, I'm not sure if it's actually true. There are many more questions on the network having answers that aren't up to date:

- questions about current or very recent events on Politics.SE or Sports.SE
- [support](/questions/tagged/support) questions on (a) Meta about [site functionality which doesn't exist anymore](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/71844/295232) or is drastically altered
- questions about versions of an API or platform which were heavily in use at that time, but are now considered old

If the question is popular enough, there will *always* be someone who will update the answer. Or writes a better one based on the current state of the world, like I did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33733753/4751173). IMHO, closing questions based on such an assumption isn't healthy.

Comment: That particular question is a pet project of mine. It's been recently updated, too